# I can't show the images on the new window using Python tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, gif

```
   def selection():
        picTk = Toplevel()
        picTk.title('Photos')
        picTk.geometry('900x500')
    
        image_list = os.listdir('.')
        photoimage_list = []
        for photo in image_list:
            if photo.endswith('.gif'):
                im = Image.open(photo)
                pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=im)
                photoimage_list.append(pic)
    
        n = 0
        img_show = photoimage_list[n]
        lb1 = Label(picTk,image=img_show)
        lb1.image = img_show
        lb1.place(x=10,y=10)
    
        back_btn = Button(picTk,text='<<',command=lambda:back(-1),state=DISABLED)
        back_btn.place(x=10,y=800)
    
        exit_btn = Button(picTk,text='Exit',command=picTk.destroy)
        exit_btn.place(x=300,y=800)
    
        for_btn = Button(picTk,text='>>',command=lambda:forward(0))
        for_btn.place(x=600,y=800)
        picTk.mainloop()
    
      
    
    
    tk = Tk()
    tk.title('Home')
    
    Label(tk,text='Photos of Dominic').pack(pady=10)
    Button(tk,text='View Album',command=selection).pack(pady=10)
```

Error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "E:\Python2\photo album\photo_album.py", line 15, in selection
        pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=im)
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 89, in __init__
        image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 58, in _get_image_from_kw
        return Image.open(source)
      File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2852, in open
        prefix = fp.read(16)
    AttributeError: 'GifImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

When I clicked the button View Album then the above error message appeared. I tried a lot of times within a day and a blank window appears with no image. I keep changing and use different methods but there is still error. I also searched with different books and use the correct format already but error appears all the time. My aim is to show the picture on the second window within clicking the button View Album. If possible can anyone teach me how to solve this problem? I really need help to solve the above problem.

Comment: mayb the .gif image is the problem? is it properly formatted?

Comment: Should be `pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)` or `pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=photo)`.

Comment: I tried remove file= but still not working

Comment: I converted all photos into gif format

Comment: What is the error after removing `file=`?

Comment: I solved already by changing pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im) and the pictures can be shown

Comment: so the error is fixed?

Comment: Yes I solved the error

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you are opening the image with Image.open() then you are passing it as a file to ImageTk.PhotoImage(). To resolve this you could use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)` or simply  delete `Image.open(photo)` and use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=photo)` I hope this helps.

```py
   def selection():
        picTk = Toplevel()
        picTk.title('Photos')
        picTk.geometry('900x500')
    
        image_list = os.listdir('.')
        photoimage_list = []
        for photo in image_list:
            if photo.endswith('.gif'):
                pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=photo) # file is photo not im
                photoimage_list.append(pic)
```